# Linear scale with labels in D3

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization, graph-visualization

Is it possible in D3 to have a linear scale but use (ordinal-style) labels?

I want to display month names under X-axis. I used ordinal scale at first and it worked fine; but turns out D3 zoom doesn't work with ordinal scale.

So I want to have the linear scale(0-11 as month numbers) but somehow get month names when we render the axis. Is that possible? Any suggestions/workarounds are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved this using [Axis.tickFormat](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickFormat)

For example,

```
var y = d3.scale.linear()
.range([height, 0]);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient("left")
.ticks(5)
.tickFormat(function (d) {
    switch(d) {
        case 40: return "Monday"; break;
        case 50: return "Tuesday"; break;
        case 60: return "Wednesday"; break;
        case 70: return "Thursday"; break;
        case 80: return "Friday"; break;
    }
});
```

Comment: you can create an array for all months, and use function (d) { return arr[d]; } in the tickformat() too

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Definitely much cleaner .

Comment: Just realized, doesn't `d` refer to the actual tick value? eg. in the above example, `d` will take values 40, 50, etc. then how can I use `arr[d]` ? I tried `function (d, i)` but it's giving error

Answer (score 2):

should work like this below, but you'll need to map your 'data' accordingly.

```
var data = [40,50,60,70,80]
var days = ["Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri"]

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient("left")
.ticks(5)
.tickFormat(function (d,i) {
    return days[i];
});
```